# Hibernate deletes Lazy loaded many-to-many collection when a get call is made on the collection

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-security, many-to-many, ehcache

I am trying to fetch roles from database using hibernate in java application. I am undergoing a many to many mapping for the same.

After fetching the data, it is getting deleted from database. I am not calling the delete method either still the deletion occurs.
**Role.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ROLE") 
public class Role extends BaseModel implements java.io.Serializable {

private Long id;
private Set<User> users = new HashSet<User>(0); 


@Id
@Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false, scale = 0)
public Long getId() {
    return this.id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}


@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "roles")
@JoinTable(name = "USERROLEMAP", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "ROLEID", nullable = false, updatable = false) }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "USERID", nullable = false, updatable = false) })
public Set<User> getUsers() {
    return this.users;
}

public void setUsers(Set<User> users) {
    this.users = users;
}

}
```

**User.java**

```
@Cacheable
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "LOGINID"))
public class User extends BaseModel implements java.io.Serializable {

private Long id;

private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<Role>(0);


@Id
@Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false, scale = 0)
public Long getId() {
    return this.id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}


@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "USERROLEMAP", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "USERID", nullable = false, updatable = false) }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "ROLEID", nullable = false, updatable = false) })
public Set<Role> getRoles() {
    return this.roles;
}

}
```

We are trying to get the roles from database using the following code snippet

```
public List<String> rolesAsGA() {
    List<String> proxyUserRoles = new ArrayList<String>();
    Iterator<Role> itr = getRoles().iterator();
    while (itr.hasNext()) {
        proxyUserRoles.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(itr.next()
                .getRoleName()));
    }
    return proxyUserRoles;
}
```

after fetching the roles the data (corresponding role) is getting deleted simultaneously, can anyone tell me why?

**Edit -** We are debugging in eclipse and hibernate is marking the collection for removal since, currentPersistor becomes null for the collection entity. Will debug further and post any update to it.

**Edit 1** We missed to mention that, User was @Cacheable, and was being fetched from ehcache, When the getRole call was being made, the collection gets loaded by then prompty queued for deletion. Removing the @Cacheable annotation fixes the problem. 
Do i create a seperate question regarding @Cacheable and manytomany or shall i just update this question  and hope for a proper solution?

Comment: Where are you retrieving the data? They querying part?

Comment: The User object is retrieved using JPARepository finder method.

Comment: Post the querying details.

Comment: @Thihara, the issue seems to be Ehcache & manytomany mapping issue. The User object was being fetched from Ehcache, and then when the getRoles was fired, the data is fetched but then marked for deletion. Removing the @ Cacheable annotation solves the deletion problem. Is there a way in which, we map User Cacheable but lazy load the roles or other manytomany associations later?

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is causing an issue

```
private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<Role>(0);

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "USERROLEMAP", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "USERID", nullable = false, updatable = false) }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "ROLEID", nullable = false, updatable = false) })
public Set<Role> getRoles() {
    return this.roles;
}
```

It should be

```
 private Set<Role> roles;

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "USERROLEMAP", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "USERID", nullable = false, updatable = false) }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "ROLEID", nullable = false, updatable = false) })
public Set<Role> getRoles() {
    if(roles == null){
         return new HashSet<Role>;
    }
    return this.roles;
}
```

Because whenever getRoles is called, it will always return an empty set. So hibernate is assuming that you have actually emptied/deleted the set and deleting them in Database

Comment: Not necessarily. Roles will be initialized only once. During the class creation time. After that it will not reinitialize an empty set, how are you saying that it will always return am empty set?? If the set is added to the class after the class is instantiated it won't happen right??

Comment: The init to null did not help. 

  
did the change as suggested and the mapping table data is still deleted for the selected user

Comment: @Thihara Yes. I was thinking something else. Sorry.